# Simon Says game - Activating Light X when Button X(randomly selected) lights up

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm a game design student and as my final work, our professor asked us to make a simple game based on a historic event of our country. I chose the construction of the "Christ the Redeemer" statue. The rule of the project was that we could only use 4 colors, so I decided to make a game based on "Simon Says".

Basically, as you get the correct sequence of the buttons, parts of the statue are built. This is ready and working. To spice things I, I thought it would be nice to activate some spotlights below the statue that light up according to their respective colors on the Simon Says. So, if the button green on the Simon Says lights up, the green spotlight should play an animation (or turn on and off shortly), and so forth.

This seems to be challenging as the buttons are played randomly. Unfortunately, after several days of attempting I cannot get this to work through triggers, animations, etc. I've tried endlessly looking on youtube and google with no luck. Can anybody give me a guiding light?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVzoV.jpg (I left the lights on to better understand my concept).

I've tried making separate scripts on the lights and having a message sent to them to play an animation. I've tried activating and deactivating the gameobject by attaching the lights to the buttons (when pressed, lights on/off)

```
[DisallowMultipleComponent]
[RequireComponent(typeof(AudioSource))]
public class Button : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int ButtonIndex { get; set;}

    [SerializeField] Color defaultColor;
    [SerializeField] Color highlightColor;
    [SerializeField] float resetDelay = .25f;
    [SerializeField] GameManager gm;
    AudioSource sound;

    private void Awake()
    {
        sound = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        ResetButton();
    }

    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        gm.PlayerPick(ButtonIndex);
        PressButton();
    }

    public void PressButton()
    {
        sound.Play();
        GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color = highlightColor;
        Invoke("ResetButton", resetDelay);
    }

    void ResetButton()
    {
        GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.color = defaultColor;
    }
}
```

```
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] Button[] button;
    [SerializeField] PlayMenu playmenu;
    [Header("Color Order")]
    [SerializeField] List<int> ButtonOrder;
    [SerializeField] float pickDelay = .4f;
    [SerializeField] int pickNumber = 0;
    [SerializeField] Score score;
    AudioSource Musica;

    void Start()
    {
        ResetGame();
        SetButtonIndex();
    }

    void SetButtonIndex()
    {
        for (int cnt = 0; cnt < button.Length; cnt++)
            button[cnt].ButtonIndex = cnt;
    }

    public void StartGame()
    {
        score.GameStarted();
        StartCoroutine("PlayGame");
    }

    public IEnumerator PlayGame()
    {
        pickNumber = 0;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(pickDelay);
        foreach (int colorIndex in ButtonOrder)
        {
            button[colorIndex].PressButton();
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(pickDelay);
        }
        PickRandomButton();

        for (int cnt = 0; cnt < 0; cnt++)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(pickDelay);
            PickRandomButton();
        }
    }

    void PickRandomButton()
    {
        int rnd = Random.Range(0, button.Length);
        button[rnd].PressButton();
        ButtonOrder.Add(rnd);
    }

    public void PlayerPick(int pick)
    {
        Debug.Log("Jogador pickou"+ pick);
        if (pick == ButtonOrder[pickNumber])
        {
            Debug.Log("Acertou");
            pickNumber++;

            if (pickNumber == ButtonOrder.Count)
            {
                score.Set(pickNumber);
                //colocar score aqui no futuro
                StartCoroutine("PlayGame");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Errou");
            ResetGame();
            playmenu.Activate();
        }      
    }

    void ResetGame()
    {
        Debug.Log("Recomecar o jogo");
        ButtonOrder.Clear();
        score.Set();
        score.Restart();
    }
}
```

With everything I've tried, the game will still play, although the buttons become unselectable thus impossible to continue gameplay. (and lights will not go on)

Comment: Do not post a screenshot of your code, post the code itself here. Please include `Button` class definition in your post to make it easier for everyone.

Comment: Hi, abdusco. I've put both codes up to make it easier as you requested. Thanks a lot for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

As you stated you dont know which button you press, but this shouldnt be a problem if you work with an enum and then a switch instead of working directly with the button index, so i leave some guide code, i hope it helps

```
    public enum Buttons
    {
        BLUE,
        GREEN,
        YELLOW
    }

    void PickRandomButton()
    {
        int rnd = Random.Range(0, button.Length);
        AnimateAndSavePickedButton((Buttons)rnd);
        ButtonOrder.Add(rnd);
    }

    void AnimateAndSavePickedButton(Buttons button)
    {
        switch (button)
        {
            case Buttons.BLUE:
                button[0].PressButton();
                //here your activation event for the blue light
                break;
            case Buttons.GREEN:
                button[1].PressButton();
                //here your activation event for the green light
                break;
            case Buttons.YELLOW:
                button[2].PressButton();
                //here your activation event for the yellow light
                break;
        }
    }
```